# Asciidoctor: activate substitution in CLI attributes

Tags: attributes, asciidoc, asciidoctor, antora

It seems that the inline macro `pass` does not work for CLI attributes.

If I render the following snippet:

```
:foo: crazy
:bar: pass:q,a[{foo} *world*]

hello {bar}
```

I get what I expect: *hello crazy **world***

But if I pass the two attributes to the CLI (`asciidoctor-pdf -a foo=crazy -a bar='pass:q,a[{foo} *world*]' foo.adoc`), it does not work:

*hello pass:q,a[{foo} *world*]*

What can I do to make it work?

To add a little context, I plan to use antora to write the documentation of the software I am developing. I would like to define attributes in the `antora-playbook.yml` or the `antora.yml` to act as 'latex macros'.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes specified on the command-line are treated as strings, not Asciidoc markup. That means that the `pass` macro isn't being processed.

However, by default, attributes specified on the command-line override attributes specified within a document. So, you can use your document as described above, with the attribute definitions included, and then you can run:

```sh
asciidoctor-pdf -a foo=stable foo.adoc
```

The command-line definition for the `foo` attribute overrides the in-document definition, and the result is `hello stable world`.

Comment: Yes, but my point is not to have the attributes specified in the document (in order to 'centralize' their definitions), so I would like to have 'bar' also on the CLI

Comment: You can specify the string values for attributes on the command-line. You cannot specify Asciidoc markup as an attribute value on the command-line. To achieve what you desire would require a code change, and could be tricky to implement without introducing unexpected behavior into an existing doc production workflow. A pull request would be welcome.